# Populate column based on dropdown selection

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dropdown

[image: Screenshot]

I have an Excel worksheet with two tables: Table 1 serves as a summary table and table 2 has 12 columns each representing a month. In table 2 I have unique data stored under each month. I have a dropdown list above one of the table 1 columns and this dropdown list consist of the month names.

I want to select a month from the dropdown list and have the data of that month stored in table 2 to basically mirror in table 1 for summary.

Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Can you please post an example of the tables, I think `vlookup` will do what you need

Comment: How many rows you have in table 2? Is it 1 row (excluding header)? If yes then you can copy paste row&col -> col&row then do vlookup.

Comment: I added an image, I would like to choose a value from the list highlighted in yellow and then show the corresponding column from the right hands side table in the left hand side table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put my *Table2* in **A1** through **L18** and my *Table1* in column **N**.  In **N1** enter the drop-down and in **N2** enter:

```
=INDEX(A$2:L$18,ROWS($1:1),MATCH($N$1,A$1:L$1,0))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: Works like magic, thanks a lot! What is this method used? is this a VLOOKUP?

Comment: @Solx85  **similar to** VLOOKUP()..................typical use of *MATCH()* and *INDEX()* functions.